# How do I list connected displays using the command line?

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, hardware, display, monitor

Is there a command that will list displays connected to the computer?

Specifically, I'm looking to find out how my external monitor is being detected by the system when connected by HDMI cable and what it's (not sure of the correct term here) hardware address is (eg. "CRT-0" or "DFP-1").

This is just a general question, but for reference, I'm using:

- Asus UL30JT laptop - running Ubuntu 12.04 beta and 11.10
- Asus PA238 23" monitor
- HDMI 1.4 cable
- Optimus graphics (Intel + nVidia GeForce 310M) - running with [Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)

Answer (score 55):

Try this:

```
xrandr --query
```

This lists the display names and detected available resolutions. You can also reconfigure your displays using xrandr.

Note that this might not work if you're using the NVidia or ATI drivers; I'm not sure.

Comment: xrandr only works when you run it under X-windows. After all, it is X that handles all but the most basic video drivers. If you are in a terminal inside X and it still doesn't work, then you've most likely lost your `$DISPLAY` environment variable, somehow.

Comment: Don't forget to add `-display :0.0` if trying this from remote log-in (putty?).

Comment: `xrandr --query | grep '\bconnected\b'` if you just wanted to see the connected monitors and their resolutions.

Comment: @NikolaMalešević Now it's changed from `Can't open display` to `Can't open display :0.0`  :|

Comment: @mpen `xrandr --listconnectedmonitors` surely?

Answer (score 11):

For most machines with the proprietary driver loaded, `/usr/lib/nvidia-current/bin/nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info --nvidia-cfg-path=/usr/lib/nvidia-current` works. Note that I said "with the proprietary driver loaded". For instance, it does not work if the driver is unloaded or nouveau is loaded. Therefore, when using Bumblebee, run `optirun /usr/lib/nvidia-current/bin/nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info`. The `--nvidia-cfg-path` part is not needed here as `optirun` sets the correct library path.

See also the discussion on https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/21

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (where 0 is the display number) may also contain valuable information about available screens. For Optimus laptops, this log contains only details on the Intel screen, so replace `0` by `8` to find out the log from the X server started by Bumblebee.

Comment: +1, This works when there are multiple graphics cards, whereas the `xrandr` answer does not.