# Start video with VLC on Linux from Windows PC using ssh or Putty

Tags: ssh, video, vlc, putty

I need to start videos on the Linux computer. I am not always able to access it directly. I am using Windows PC and I can ssh to that Linux PC. Do we have any way to start the video to play in VLC using ssh, putty, or something else?
I do not need the screen on Windows PC - I want to start it and displayed it on Linux.

Thank you,

Comment: Does the Linux computer (where you are SSHing to) have a display?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot SSH to an existing session which is already connected to a display. Instead, use RealVNC Server and Viewer to remote control. https://www.realvnc.com/en/

Comment: ssh -X ip_addr "vlc /path/to/file.mp4 "

Comment: you have the 'RC' feature of VLC, can be controlled via browser, another vlc app, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can run graphical application on Ubuntu over ssh connection.

1. First find out value of DISPLAY variable set by display server on Ubuntu machine[1].
2. From your Windows PC connect to your Ubuntu machine using ssh client(I think windows 10 has a preinstalled ssh client)
3. Run

```
export DISPLAY=:0
vlc -I ncurses file.mp4
```

Change the value of `DISPLAY` accordingly. Commands above will open VLC on Ubuntu machine and you'll be able to control playback (using ncurses interface) from your windows machine. See [0] for more information on how to control VLC interface.

[0] https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/ncurses/

[1] If your Ubuntu machine is inaccessible directly, you can check `$HOME/.xsession-errors` file for the `DISPLAY` variable or check [How do I list connected displays using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121014/how-do-i-list-connected-displays-using-the-command-line)